# how to specify publication name in SearchQueryData

Tags: core-service

I'm trying to get all the components modified after a particular date using core service

Here is the code:

```
            // Search query
            SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 03, 25);
            filter.ModifiedAfter = date;
            filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[]
            {
                ItemType.Component,
                ItemType.ComponentTemplate,
                ItemType.Page,
                                 ItemType.PageTemplate,
                ItemType.Publication,
                ItemType.Schema
            };

            //returns the list of items changed by date
            IdentifiableObjectData[] data = client.GetSearchResults(filter);
```

The code returns me all the components that got changed after  the specified date accross all the publications.

Is there anyway to search the modified components in a particular publication using SearchQueryData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but there's a catch. Items can be shared, or localized in the publication you are interested in, so apart from setting publication you also need to set the `BlueprintStatus`. So:

```
filter.BlueprintStatus = SearchBlueprintStatus.Unspecified; // or anything else
filter.FromRepository = new LinkToPublicationData{ IdRef = pubId };
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the revision history of categories, keywords, structure groups and folders

Comment: No, these are not versioned items, so you can only get the last changed time and revisor

Comment: I checked but it doesnot show the version history of folders, SG, categories and keywords...it only gives the version history for components CT,PT, pages,TBB.

Comment: Even in tridion there if you right click the Categories there is no option to check the version history

Comment: Please ask a separate question as we are polluting this one