# Can we customize Tridion Search?

Tags: 2013-sp1, search, search-engine

Business Requirement is to make tridion search flexible for any content files/items across (ideally) whole CMS library. It means it some pdf file is attached in a multimedia component, Tridion search should be able to fetch this pdf by its name. Is it possible?

Note: I am thinking to create a custom page with extended Search functionality, . Does anybody knows if we have something in alchemy for this kind of search ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work (as expected)? If not, can you elaborate on the requirements?  In general, the CM Search Engine (Solr) will index binary content of certain formats (incl. PDFs)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt search by PDF *filename* is possible, by default. As @Rick mentioned, content *in* the PDF is searchable.

The [documentation lists supported formats](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CB860676-0A4D-4A30-92B2-1C0D240513C6):

- HTML
- XML and derived formats
- Microsoft Office documents
- OpenDocument documents
- PDF documents
- EPUB (Electronic Publication Format) documents
- RTF (Rich Text Format) documents

It also notes you cannot search for a Multimedia Component with (by?) its file extension.

I'd suggest confirming if editors can find what they're looking for and if not, then consider @Marko's examples and custom search. You might start with showing either the path or filename to the user, since it'll help confirming the search actually found what they're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more custom functionality, then you need to develop your own custom search using core service. For this you can use `SearchQueryData` class:
[image]

Also, you can take a look at the following blogs how to perform search in Content Manager:
http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/06/performing-search-queries-with-core.html

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/search-components-pages-from-tridion-cms-and-generate-report-in-csv-format

or even stack exchange questions:
[how to specify publication name in SearchQueryData](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11505/how-to-specify-publication-name-in-searchquerydata)

Comment: Thanks @marko , yes i am thinking to create a custom page with extended search functionality.